# leader selection

Tags: algorithm, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, master-slave, distributed-system

I have x machines and I want to select 1 to do a particular job (primary machine). I have a database which is the only shared resource these machines have and there is no inter machine communication mechanism.

In order to select a machine, I'm thinking of writing a value to the db and whichever succeeds first is selected (say M1). M1 periodically updates database to say its alive. When M1 dies, other machines seeing that M1 hasn't updated DB recently, will try to write to db to assume the primary machine role.

What value can I have the machines write to db at any given point in time, so every machine tries to write the same value? If the clocks are synchronized in all the machines, I can possibly take YYMMDDHHMM. But that might not be the case.

Any pointers/ideas?

Comment: Why would every machine write the same value? Surely M1 has to write something different to what M2 would write so M2 knows that M1 got there first.

Comment: Can't you use the DBMS's functionality to query the time on the server itself?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek, thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer to make you aware of some issues you might have to deal with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DBMS's functionality to query the time on the server itself to follow the approach that you are outlining here.

To make this watertight, there are a few issues you will have to take care of though:

- When testing the liveliness of the current worker node, a write lock will have to be acquired on the table to make sure the testing of the worker liveliness and the claiming of the job are done as one atomic action. This avoids simultaneous claiming by multiple workers.
- Whenever the current worker updates the table to assert its liveliness, it will have to follow the same mechanism of locking in order to detect the case that any other worker has taken over the job
- In order to even know that some other worker has taken over the job, you will need to include some kind of identification so it is visible who is currently doing the job

These are just generic remarks because from your description it is not exactly clear how you want to implement the algorithm in all detail.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what lock semantics your database gives you, and how good it is at detecting failed clients, it might be enough for each machine to attempt to acquire a common exclusive lock. Whichever machine gets the exclusive lock is the leader.

Comment: If you choose to do this, it's useful for debugging to also log when and which machine picked up the lock. An append only table is useful for this. Also, make sure you test semantics when a connection is lost due to an ungraceful shutdown. You will be at the mercy of the database's keep alive and you will want to know how long you might be without a leader.